# Vector to a string and HashMap in C++

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-map

I am beginning with vector and unordered_map in C++. But I don't understand the reason of the error when accessing a value of the map by its key.

First I define a vector of integers as follows :

```
std::vector <int> vec;
vec.push_back(1);
vec.push_back(5);
vec.push_back(1);
```

then I convert the vector to a string:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
if (!vec.empty())
   std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(),std::ostream_iterator<int>(oss));

std::string s = oss.str();
const void * s1=s.c_str();
```

and I create my map :

```
std::unordered_map<const void *, const void *> map1;

map1[s1]="Hello";
```

Here, if s1 is equal to "151", why can't I obtain the value "Hello" of the key "151" like this :

```
std::cout << (char *) map1["151"] << std::endl;
```

unlike this :

```
const char* s2 = "180"
map1[s2]="World"
std::cout <<"The value of the key '180' :" << (char *) map1["180"] << std::endl;
```

Here, I can have "The value of the key '180' : World" displayed.

So what is really s1 ? Isn't it the string "151" ?

Comment: Just add `std::cout << oss.str() << std::endl;` and see what it prints. Why asking something that you can check by yourself with 0 effort?

Comment: Already done, and it prints "151"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the view of a `std::unordered_map<const void *, const void *>`, `map1[s1]` is different from `map1["151"]`, because the `unordered_map` just compare the key by the value of the pointer, not the value the pointer points to.

And in the 2nd code, `s2` points to the literal c-style string `"180"`, so `map1[s2]` and `map1["180"]` could get the same value, because they're pointing to the same thing.

According to the declaration of [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map),

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Hash = std::hash<Key>,
    class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator< std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class unordered_map;
```

`std::unordered_map` use [std::equal_to](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to) as its default key comparer, which just use `operator==` for comparing.

You can provide your own comparer for `std::unordered_map` to change the behaviour, like

```
std::unordered_map<const void*, const void*, std::hash<const void*>, my_comparer> map1;
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand the foolish thing... Solved with just replacing     std::unordered_map<const void *, const void *> by     std::unordered_map<std::string, const void *>.
But I will write my own comparer for further work.

Comment: @user2695912 Yes, it's a good idea to use STL usually. `std::string` has implemented the comparer itself.